# Toad Notation - What do (Ix#)'s mean?

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, toad, erd

So, I'm trying to visualize a database, and I have some tables put together which consist of a mix of object-oriented and relational; just trying to tie them together.

My issue is, I can't seem to find any info on the notation/legend - and I'm having trouble figure out what all the (Ix#)'s are.  For Example, in the top left corner table "NC_PO_ACTIONS," for the Column ACTION_ID: I can see it's a primary key, but not sure what (Ix3) means...

I've looked at all the user guides I could find, as well as the help menu within Toad.

[image]

Comment: also, I'm inclined to think it has to do with Index's and index columns...just want to be 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those are indexes. On the left side choose the Diagram tab. You can expand the tables there and see additional information including the indexes. You can also press F4 when an object is selected to get Toad's popup Describe window which will contain much more information for the selected object.

[image]

Comment: while you have that up, can i ask what those yellow filing-cabinet icons to the left of the column names are?  have a suspicion it means the columns are objects?

Comment: I have no idea! I've been looking and surprisingly cannot locate a legend. Similarly I cannot locate a legend searching the Toad Data Modeler documentation. Toad Data Modeler is a separate product, but its code is what drives the ER Diagram and Code Road Map in Toad for Oracle. If I come across the answer I will post back.

Comment: thanks! I'm trying to make sense of a O/R data base, and am looking for the best approach to visualize the whole thing - any advice on where to look?  this mix of objects and relational is a bit hairy...

Comment: Disclaimer: I am a developer for Quest and Toad for Oracle, but since you are using Toad I would post a question to our forums. https://forums.toadworld.com/c/toad-for-oracle. We have seasoned database professionals there that might be able to provide some tips and tricks for breaking down your task into manageable pieces. I'm also a huge fan of StackOverflow, but your question is very broad in nature and I believe these types of questions are generally frowned upon here. StackOverflow seems best suited for specific questions showing your efforts and ending with an issue to solve.